# BMR VS muscle weight?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, exercise, diet, body-fat

Jim has 50kg of muscle.

Lee has 25kg of muscle.

They both are 100kg, 20yo, male, eat 2000cal every day, consume same things, do the same things, live in the same place. Basically only difference is the muscle weight.

Lee's BMR is 2000cal. What would be the Jim's BMR?

> Basal metabolic rate (BMR) is the amount of energy expended while at rest in a neutrally temperate environment

PS: There are quite a few assumption here. I'm aware that it is impossible to answer this question precisely with or without assumptions.

Comment: This isn't really related to fitness, it's more a general formula theory question, and all you really have to do is plug numbers into either Katch-McCardle or the Cunningham equations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about formula differences, not fitness.

Comment: Then how do I plug numbers into either Katch-McCardle or the Cunningham equations?

Comment: There are numerous web sites and App's that will crunch the numbers for you.